# Enterprise Manager cannot connect to 11g database instance

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-enterprise-manager

In Oracle 11g when we are opening OEM in browser it is showing the following message :

"**Enterprise Manager is not able to connect the database instance.**"
Listener status is showing Up and 
Agent Connection to instance the status is showing unavailable.

please provide a solution.

I am attaching a screenshot of my problem. I still did not find any solution yet.plz help
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may need to resecure the agent. Here is a link that should help.

http://jhdba.wordpress.com/2008/12/10/clearing-an-enterprise-manager-agent-that-fails-to-upload/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but whatever you have provided are related to Unix, my environment is windows 7. can u please share some link related to windows 7 platform.

Comment: The steps are the same you would just do them from the command prompt rather than a shell prompt. You should make sure that the dbsnmp account is known and not locked in the target database.

Comment: sysman account is locked again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reset the "dbsnmp" user's password from the database.  Then update the password of dbsnmp user in OEM:

Targets --> Select database and press "Configure".

Comment: http://www.oracledistilled.com/grid-control/metric-collection-error-after-fresh-install-of-oracle-enterprise-manager-11gr1-grid-control/